# Angular form validation disable submit button

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-forms

In my form I check the name and email validation with name

```
<input matInputrequired 
       minlength="3" 
       placeholder="Name" 
       ngModel   
       name="name" 
       #firstName="ngModel"
       [(ngModel)]="apiResult.name" 
       id="firstName">
```

And email with

```
<input matInput 
       placeholder="Email" 
       ngModel name="email" 
       maxlength="100" 
       #email="ngModel" 
       email 
       [(ngModel)]="apiResult.email" 
       id="email">
```

if the name field is empty and less than 3 characters. email is not required but if user added an email it should in email format. then if these are success only enable the submit button.

Answer (score 12):

What is your question?

If you want to see an example of building a simple form with validation check out the movie-edit.component.html file in this repo: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter

It contains code to disable the submit/save button like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]='!editForm.valid'>
    Save
</button>
```

Answer (score 10):

Okay we can use template driven form:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
   Your email and username inputs

   <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: but the matter is when it is empty the email field also get validation error I want to check only email is not empty then it should validate. because email is not required.

Comment: (name.valid AND (if(email is not emty) then(email is valid))) something like this

Comment: Email input field should not show empty validation error unless you add required validation, also the form is valid only if all it's control is valid. So, if you want the email to be checked only if you required it.

Comment: I want to check the email in email format if user entered an email so I used html email field for input. then form.valid get an error with email empty

Answer (score 2):

Use `[disabled]="myForm.invalid"`:

```html
<button [disabled]="myForm.invalid" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
<button [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
```